# display lines which start with many pattern

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression

**how to display lines which start with many pattern:**

```
[*] 3 
[*] 4 
[*] 5 
[*] 6
```

Using sed command: `sed '/[*]/!d' file` i were able to display lines starting with `[*]`

so am looking to find lines which start with `[*] 3` OR `[*] 4` OR `[*] 5`

so how to handle it because there's one space before the digit as above input.

Comment: what are you exactly trying to do? To delete lines which only start with `[*]` without any following characters?

Comment: sorry i edited the question, wanna display lines start with `[*] 3` OR `[*] 4` OR `[*] 5`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest if you don't mind, in case if i would like to remove `[*]` and spaces in lines, which sed command shall i use.

Comment: here `sed 's/^\[\*\][[:space:]]*//' file`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i applied the command on file containing such of the following line `[*] 111, 22, 33, 44` but it's print it out as `111, 22, 33, 44` but am looking to get the line as `111,22,33,44`

Comment: that's another input case, feel free to create a new question for that case (don't forget to prepare it properly)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest :( ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight **sed** approach:

```
sed '/^\[\*\][[:space:]]*[0-9]/!d' file
```

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
grep '^\[\*\] [3,4,5,6]' input.txt
```

or using range for numbers `[3-6]`

```
grep '^\[\*\] [3-6]' input.txt
```